# Why did JJ Abrams recreate the Star Trek Timeline?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-reboot

In the 2009 version of Star Trek, Nero and the Romulans come back through time via Blackhole and kill Kirk's dad and the original Star Trek timeline is altered  creating a whole new reality.

Why would Abrams not just stick to the timeline given by Roddenberry instead of altering it?

Comment: i don't think we're gonna be able to answer this other than 'because he wanted to'...

Comment: there must be a better reason than that

Comment: Because he's a schmuck.

Comment: @Fingolfin why do you think there's a better reason than "because that's the movie the director wanted to make"?

Comment: So he could use more lens flare.

Comment: The 2009 Star Trek is a reboot of the entire series. Reboots often (read: almost always) change the previous telling's timeline of events. Abrams was not a fan of Star Trek and wanted to tell it in a new way that would be enjoyable for people under the age of 40. And yes, the lens flare use was gratuitous.

Comment: @TylerH I find it mildly revolting that somebody who was "was not a fan of Star Trek" would be allowed to meddle with it.  Why don't we just let Trek haters have a hack at it to while we are at it?  That said, as as an over 40 person, I found the movies enjoyable excluding specifically the wrecking of the timeline via a vastly sub-optimal use of time travel.  I think there were far better possibilities not involving any of the original crew, but then again, I'm not a big fan of reboots as I don't find them particularly creative (come up with something new, guys!)

Comment: @Michael Hey, I didn't say I agreed with the idea to give it to Mr. Lens Flare! Just giving some more information to help combat the noisy comments above by Richard and M. Edenfield

Comment: Why are you putting all the blame on Abrams, and not the producers etc. who hired him? Abrams doesn't own the IP, someone wanted him to make the movies this way.

Comment: Because otherwise, you know everything that's going to happen. According to one of the writers (I forget which), they wanted Kirk being in danger to feel real, not safe because you know he actually gets a rock dropped on him by Malcom McDowell in fifty years time.

Comment: It can't be a coincidence that the highest-rated Star Trek works are those that set out boldly in new stylistic directions and were helmed by newcomers to the franchise (TNG, Khan), while the lowest-rated are those created by existing fans (Enterprise season 1+2). History has *shown* that existing fans don't create good new content. They don't have stories to tell or visions to realize; they just circlejerk over continuity.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TL;DR. Because he [never especially cared for the original Star Trek](http://www.startrek.com/article/abrams-talks-trek-2009-during-podcast) and because he felt restricted (as a Director) by the existing canon universe:

> **Abrams:** I was, frankly, never really a fan. I never really got it. I never really cared much about it. Most of my friends who loved
> it were, without question, smarter than I was. I kept trying... and I
> couldn’t get it. I didn’t care about it. It felt stilted. It is ironic
> because a lot of the tone and techniques and some of the writers as
> well were from The Twilight Zone. When you watch it, you’d go, ‘God,
> there is that same kind of melodramatic vibe.’ A lot of the writers
> were the same writers. You’d think someone who loved The Twilight Zone
> as much as I did would kind of find a kinship to that show and get on
> board. I couldn’t do it. I enjoyed the movies that I saw, the early
> films, but I never looked forward to them. **So, when I was mixing
> Mission: Impossible III… I was asked if I was interested in producing
> a Star Trek movie. When I said yes, it was because… I’d never thought
> of it, ever… but what occurred to me as I was being asked was "There’s
> a version of it that I could see getting interested in." And it was
> weird, because I couldn’t tell you what it was. I just knew that if
> Star Trek were done in a certain way, with an approach that somehow
> let me in more… I was actually being given the opportunity to at least
> attempt to do something that I wished had existed for me as a kid
> trying to get into it, which is a way in, which is an emotional way
> in, that was not was not about the Enterprise or Starfleet or the
> Prime Directive or any of that stuff, that was completely emotional. I
> thought if that existed I probably would have found a way in.** Now,
> maybe I saw the wrong episodes. Maybe I wasn’t in the right frame of
> mind as a kid. I don’t know what it was. I have since watched a number
> of them and actually have actually come to really appreciate the
> show.
>
> **Abrams:** Here’s the thing… I think the key to that was, first of all, it was one of those things that not everyone even cares about or
> understands the timeline of it all. The notion that when this one
> character, Nero, arrives in his ship, that basically the timeline is
> altered at that moment, so everything forward is essentially an
> alternative timeline. **That is not to say that everything that happened
> in The Original Series doesn’t exist. I think, as a fan of movies and
> shows, if someone told me the beloved thing for me was gone, I would
> be upset. But we didn’t do that.  We’re not saying that what happened
> in that original series wasn’t good, true, valid, righteous and real.
> Let people embrace that. We’re not rejecting that. That, to me, would
> have been the big mistake. We’re simply saying that, "At this moment,
> the very first scene in the first movie, everything that people knew
> of Star Trek splits off into now another timeline."**

Comment: So, in other words - he was trying to keep people from accusing him of ruining the original? :3

Comment: @recognizer - Worse. He wanted to make Star Trek *his way*. He repeatedly said that he'd be true to Rodenberry's vision, then proceeded to ignore 50 years of continuity.

Comment: He could've done things his way WITHOUT the parallel timeline - but then he'd have had it even worse, as we'd also be furious that he gave everyone a new origin story that didn't fit into continuity at all. To be honest, the parallel timeline let me accept a lot of stuff in Abrams' first ST film that I wouldn't have otherwise.

Comment: @recognizer - I have no issues with a rebooted continuity. I do have a real problem with the way that they crapped on the entire established "universe" when a ten minute chat with a room full of fans would have immediately showed them what mistakes they were making. Also, lens flare.

Comment: As a fan of the regular series as well as next generation, I really enjoyed the new star trek movies. I wouldn't say it was better or worse, just different, and I loved it. -shrug-

Comment: @TaylorAllred - And that's the rub. The movies aren't made for uber-fans, they're made for a mass audience.

Comment: @Richard  The biggest disappointment to me was that Abrams ignored the tone of ST.  ST (In Roddenberry's eyes) was an optimistic future that framed current moral issues with cool action oriented SciFi.  Abrams ignored that and made an action movie.  It is a great action movie, a terrible star trek movie.

Comment: @Chris - +1 to this sentiment. There seems to be a real interest in the past 10 years in taking generic action films and just slapping a brand on them. Essentially there's no difference between NuTrek and an *unbranded* space action film except for the marketing and a couple of lines for each character.

Comment: The main reason: The TOS movies made lots of cash...

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, Misha Rosnach: [comments moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57999/discussion-on-answer-by-valorum-why-did-jj-abrams-recreate-the-star-trek-timelin); please continue the conversation there.